# mongoose validate object structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I want the the property "localized_words" to be an object mapping string to **array**.

With the following code, I can only ensure it's an Object, but how can I ensure the values are **strictly array**?

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
   // example
   // this should fail   : { en: [], fr: 123 }
   // this should succeed: { en: [], fr: []  }
   // but with current code, any object will pass validation
   localized_words : { type: Object }
});
```

Example of data I want to store: `{en: ['car', 'apple'], fr: ['voiture', 'pomme']}`

Comment: Can you include example data which you want to store?

Comment: @Khang just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
   localized_words : {
       en: [String],
       fr: [String],
   },
});
```